# I can't find a way to set a rtingtone from the asset folder in android Studio

Tags: java, android, uri, assets

Hello stackoverflow community. I know this question have been made before, but in the answers always something left and my lack of expertise prevents me to deduce the rest.

the thing is, I'm developing my first android app, it sets ringtones from folders inside the assets folder.

I already managed to play the sound files from assets but can't find the way  to get the Uri path to set the same audio file as a ringtone.

Please I need help!

```
ListView assetsListView;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter   =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList); 
        assetsListView                      = findViewById(R.id.assetsListView);
        final AssetManager assetManager     = getAssets();


        System.out.println("ASSES" + assetManager);


        //***************************** listting files from the assets folder    ***********************//
        try {
            // for assets folder add empty string
            String[] fileList = assetManager.list("");
            if (fileList == null) {
                // dir does not exist or is not a directory
            } else {
                for (int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++) {
                    // Get filename of file or directory
                    String filename = fileList[i];
                }
            }

            // for assets/subFolderInAssets add only subfolder name
            String[] fileListInSubfolder = assetManager.list("ringtones");
            System.out.println("filesinsubfolder " + (fileListInSubfolder == null));
            if(fileListInSubfolder == null) {
                 // dir does not exist or is not a directory
             }else{
                 for (int i=0; i < fileListInSubfolder.length; i++) {
                     // get filename from files in the subdirectory

                     String filenameSubD = fileListInSubfolder[i];
                     System.out.println("FILENAME IN SUBFOLDER plin:  " + filenameSubD.substring(0,(int)filenameSubD.length()-4));  // cuts the extension of the file
                     arrayList.add(filenameSubD.substring(0,(int)filenameSubD.length()-4)); /// adds the filename to the list array
                 }
             }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //******************************************************************************************//

        final boolean settingsCanWrite = Settings.System.canWrite(this);  // since API23 permission for write-settings is needed

        if(!settingsCanWrite) {                 // If do not have write settings permission then open the Can modify system settings panel.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);      // goes to settings and is needed to manually add permission to this app
            startActivity(intent);
        }else {

            assetsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            assetsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String fileName = arrayList.get(position);                   
                    String fileWithExtension = "file:///android_assets/ringtones/" + fileName;   

                    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++RINGTONE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++//

                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///android_assets/ringtones/" + fileName + ".mp3"));
                    Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("file:///android_assets/" + fileName);
                    Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("assets/ringtones/" + fileName + ".mp3");
                    Uri uri4 = Uri.parse("assets/ostinato.mp3");

                    String testFilePath = uri.getPath();
                    File file = new File("file:///android_assets/ringtones/", fileName);
                    System.out.println("FILEEE" + file);


                    System.out.println("lavativa " + uri);
                    play(fileName, uri4);


                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void play (String fileToPlayer, Uri uriPath) {         // play from the assets/ringtone folder
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("ringtones/" + fileToPlayer + ".mp3");
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                afd.close();
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {    
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    pause();
                }
            });
        } else {
            pause();
        }

        System.out.println("URI" + uriPath);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,uriPath);
        Toast.makeText(this, "message: " + uriPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226586/discussion-on-question-by-sio2-i-cant-find-a-way-to-set-a-rtingtone-from-the-as).

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the file from assets to the file system so you have a file.

Then you can use that file.

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain how could I do that? maybe help me with a piece of code